# Dask Group by and applying function return pandas dataframe instead of dask dataframe

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I want to apply Pandas UDF in dask. I tried using group by and apply user defined function, it works fine but it returns pandas dataframe instead of dask dataframe.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pack_assign_dict = {
    'clusters': ['1234', '1234', '6789', '6789', '9999', '9999'],
    'packs': ['P1', 'P2', 'P1', 'P2', 'P1', 'P2'],
    'pack_assigned': [1.95, 0.9, 1.8, 1.85, 0.25, 0.25]
}

def addititon(df1):
    df1['sum_value'] = df1['pack_assigned'].sum()
    df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['pack_assigned'])
    return df1

pack_assigned_df = pd.DataFrame(pack_assign_dict)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(pack_assigned_df, npartitions=10)
ddf1 = ddf.groupby(['clusters']).apply(addititon).compute()
```

Here datatype of ddf is dask but ddf1 dataype is pandas.

Comment: Please look up what `.compute()` does.

Comment: Yes i saw and got the answer. Compute converts data into pandas or numpy array. Basically it executes the graph.

Comment: Do you want to write that as an answer to your question? If not, you might consider deleting this question.